# Why was individual membership contribution deleted when their organizational relationship was disabled?

Tags: civicontribute, relationships

CiviCRM 5.19.2 on Drupal 7.67

We have a member who until recently was part of an organizational membership (by relationship). This year he moved on and took out an individual membership for the coming year. He paid for that himself and everything looked fine.

Then, today I disabled his relationship to his former organization (unchecked the enabled box while editing the relationship). As soon as I had done that, the contribution he had made for his individual membership disappeared!

I can confirm that it is NOT in the civicrm_contribution table. However, the transaction IS recorded in the log_civicrm_contribution table. I also have the email record of it and it's in Stripe.

Is this a major bug or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas here? Please.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a bug. There is a table "civicrm_membership_payment" which links memberships to contributions via foreign keys. If the membership gets removed, then it might be removing the corresponding contribution via these keys.
Perhaps see if you can reproduce it?